# Button with Tag

Tags: iphone, uibutton, tags

How do I get a button with the a specifyed tag

id like to then cast it to a UIButton, and change the alpha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UIView* view = [theViewContainingThatButton viewWithTag:tag];
 view.alpha = 0.5;
```

You don't need to cast the view to a UIButton to change its alpha. But you can add a `(UIButton*)` cast if really needed.

Comment: theViewContainingThatButton?

Would this be AppNameViewController?

Comment: @Sam: Any superview of that button can be used. You could use `viewController.view` or even `window`.

Answer (score 6):

```
UIButton *button=(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:tag];
button.alpha=0.5;
```